# What was the thought behind the parallel versions of Table, Map, etc..?

Tags: parallelization, core-language

There separately named versions of the parallel analogues of Map[] and friends:

```
Names @ "Parallel*"
(* returns => {"ParallelArray", "ParallelCombine", "ParallelDo", "Parallelepiped", \
"ParallelEvaluate", "Parallelization", "Parallelize", "ParallelMap", \
"ParallelNeeds", "Parallelogram", "ParallelProduct", \
"ParallelSubmit", "ParallelSum", "ParallelTable", "ParallelTry"}*)
```

From a design standpoint, I always wondered why have duplicated symbols instead of setting an option like `Parallelization -> True`?

Comment: Parallelization doesn't work very well applied globally from what I have seen, so one usually has to use it specifically.  In that case it's shorter to type `Parallel` than it is to type `, Parallelization -> True`.  Perhaps this was at least part of the reason.